# Low latency wireless audio transmitter

Tags: rf, audio, wireless, signal-processing, transmitter

I am working on a project that requires low latency wireless point to point audio transmission at short distance using a digital transmission technique  (ideally 24bit 96khz audio, 30 metre max) at a latency that is less then 5 milliseconds, the lower the better. What wireless protocols and frequency ranges are available that allows this?

Comment: Should we assume you mean digital transmission?  Most analog transmission schemes will meet your latency requirements.  Also, to get an answer on what frequency ranges are available we'll need to know what country you are in and whether this is a one-off or you are developing a commercial product.

Comment: This kind of thing is challenging in concept - either you accept missed packets, or you introduce buffering delay to permit retries.

Comment: It's called "wireless microphone" and there are already dozens of commercial solutions on the market. What is unique about your situation?

Comment: @DeanFranks I want to transmit a highest quality audio signal as possible converted from a DAC, wouldn't an analog transmission scheme introduce noise? I am in the UK ts a one-off but for the learning process, any information you have on frequency band regulations I would appreciate it

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks for your comment, I didn't think about looking at a wireless microphone system diagram. My aim of my project is for learning and for the fun of it so buying a commercial solution defeats the whole objective, the only unique situation is the audio will be sourced from a DAC interfaced with a microcontroller.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Okay thank you, do you have any suggestions on what might be an appropriate protocol?

Comment: Most modern Professional Wireless Microphones use entirely analog techniques: wide-band FM transmission and a 2:1 compander system.  They achieve around 90 dB S/N ratio (about 16 bits).